# Resolve all $refs in JSON Schema

Tags: jsonschema

I want to resolve all `$ref`s in my JSON Schema. But internal and external. Which tool provide such functionality?

Comment: I wrote this Python library/tool exactly for that: https://github.com/bagrat/dollar-ref

Answer (score -1):

tv4 allows you to resolve internal and external refs.

You have to add manually each intended external reference as [it is explained here](https://github.com/geraintluff/tv4). If an external ref has not been added, you can find it in tv4.missing.

The python json-schema validator also allows you to resolve external references if you use it with the reference module included.

You can review the [rest of implementations](http://json-schema.org/implementations.html) if you need a resolver in any other programming language.

Comment: Thanks for this. I'm looking for a `resolveAll` method. I don't want to walk the tree.